# XML file for layout not detected in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, deprecated

I am not sure what I did wrong but this issue is eating my head. In the code below, **R.layout.row** and **R.id.value** both shows up as error with the *red line* on **Eclipse** . It does say that **SimpleCursorAdapter is deprecated** but with **@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")** , it should work, right?

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        {
            adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, constantCursor, new String[] { DatabaseHelper.TITLE, DatabaseHelper.VALUE }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.value }); 

        }
        else
        {
            adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, constantCursor, new String[] { DatabaseHelper.TITLE ,DatabaseHelper.VALUE }, new int [] { R.id.title, R.id.value }); 
        }

        setListAdapter(adapter); 
    }
```

The **row.xml** which is under the ***res/layout*** directory has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you Import right R to your class? Maybe it's android.R you have import.

Comment: @JaredLuo : DAMN !! How did I overlook that... thanks a ton  :)